# Two divs inside a parent one (with a space between them)

Tags: html, css

In my provided example, the red box is the parent div and I want the other two divs inside to have the same width with a space of 10px between them. How can I achieve this?

The variables inside this two divs are dynamic but I want them to be equal width. I also want the sum of the two divs more 10px to be equal the parent div width.

https://jsfiddle.net/r0t157qx/

```
<div style="display: table; width: 100%; float:left; border-style: solid; border-color:red; border-width: 1px;">
  <div style="display: table-cell; background-color:white; border-style: solid; border-color:#EAEAEA; border-width: 1px; float: left;">
    <div style="width: 100%; background-color:#EAEAEA; text-align:left; color:#555;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:160%;text-align:justify;">
      <div style="padding-left: 9px;">
        <b>Informações de cobrança:</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; background-color:none; float:left;">
      <div style="text-align:left; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px;">
        {{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-cell; margin-left:10px; background-color:white; border-style: solid; border-color:#EAEAEA; border-width: 1px; float: left;">
    <div style="width: 100%; background-color:#EAEAEA; text-align:left; color:#555;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:160%;text-align:justify;">
      <div style="padding-left: 9px;">
        <b>Informações de entrega:</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; background-color:none; float:left;">
      <div style="text-align:left; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px;">
        {{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that the OP is not a native English speaker, so the tone may not be totally fluent.  However, he has listed his requirements and provided a demo, so the question is well posed for a first time user.

Comment: Post a question, describe you problem, what you have tried and where you are failing. Also use HTML and CSS, not inline styling for better readability.
like @WesFoster said, it is not really clear what the question is.

Comment: I not really the best writer in english! I have an issue e I would like to solve it. I don't know how to align this two divs inside the other one. Thank you, Marc! And Barthy, im using inline styling because thats how Magento reads it... I tried to use CSS in another document.

Comment: If you can use flexbox, make the parent `justify-content: space-between` and the children to have a margin right of 10px, except the last-child. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Oh the horror of inline styles :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your had the right idea using CSS tables (`display: table`).

However, you do not need to use `float` in this layout.

Here is a proof-of-concept example.

Apply `display: table` to the parent container and `display: table-cell` to the three child `div`'s.

Set a width to the `.spacer` element. The two `.column` elements will then auto-size to take up the remaining width of the table width.

**Note:** You can convert the CSS rules into inline styles as needed.

```css
.table-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-wrapper .column, .table-wrapper .spacer {
  display: table-cell;
}
h2 {
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
}
.table-wrapper .spacer {
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Your 1st Header</h2>
    <p>Some content...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Your 2nd Header</h2>
    <p>Some more content...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Mark! Thats exactly what I needed.

Comment: Please remember to upvote the question so that people know that your question has been answered.  Welcome to SO!

Comment: I did it, but i'm only 11 reputation yet. I think it does not display, but its recorded. Thank you again, you really helped me! That was really importante to me

Comment: I meant to say accept the answer, that way people know that the question is answered. Sorry about the confusion! Glad to help!

Comment: Helped me almost two years later!